# Logout SWReveal View Controller

Tags: ios, segue, logout, swrevealviewcontroller

Hello I am new to IOS and I have difficulty with some issues.
I am using SWRevealViewController and I need to log in and logout from it.

I switch between login screen and main screen in AppDelegate

```
BOOL isLoggedIn = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"islogin"];
NSString *storyboardId = isLoggedIn ? @"login_screen" : @"main_screen";
self.window.rootViewController = [self.window.rootViewController.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:storyboardId];
```

In Login view controller (I have uses show details Segue)

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"login" sender:self];
```

In Right Reveal Menu with logout TableViewCell selected (also with show detail segue)

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"logout" sender:self];
```

My question that if the user login and logout multiple times will ViewControllers go to back stack and allocate memory.

I have used show detail segue since I thought it will replace the previous view controller and what about front view controller?

Am I in the right way? please help

Comment: SWReveal View Controller has no logout function ,you need to manually handle your details if you are used push you need to pop , else if you are used modal/present you need to dismissyourViewcontroller

Comment: is there slide menu library with logout function

Answer (score 0):

You can use [MSDynamicsDrawerViewController](https://github.com/erichoracek/MSDynamicsDrawerViewController) for logout functionality. You can also use [SWRevealViewController](https://github.com/John-Lluch/SWRevealViewController), then you need to manually add the functionality of logout, because SWRevealController can not provide the logout functionality. Check this [demo](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-sidebar-navigation-menu/) how to use SWRevealController in Swift, if you are using Swift.

Comment: I'm not sure this really provides an answer to the question, perhaps you mean to make a comment?